# Agregar caracteres especiales utf-8 en (como ñ y acentos) en mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta a una tabla en `PHP` hacia `MySQL`, pero los caracteres especiales no se muestran, ¿cómo y dónde agrego el `uft-8`? ¿en la conexión o en el query?

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="basededatos1";
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);



$sql1= "SELECT * FROM registros";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>

<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<th>dato</th>
<th>dato</th>
</thead>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta @Shaz

Comment: El soporte para UTF-8 lo agregas en: 1) La codificación de tu archivo php. 2) Como etiqueta meta en la página Web. 3) Como codificación dentro de la aplicación de lado del servidor mediante `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`. 4) A nivel de base de datos, cuando creas la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas usando xampp debes configurar apache y php para que usen utf8:

**En apache:**

[httpd.conf]

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

en algunas versiones de apache no se encuentra AddDefaultCharset en el lugar habitual y tienes que buscar $cfg['DefaultCharset'] = '';
en toda la instalacion o variables similares y cambiarla por `$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf-8';`

**En php:**

[php.ini]

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=0
```

Si estas usando una versión superior o igual a php 5.6 estos parametros estan obsoletos:

```
mbstring.internal_encoding
mbstring.http_input
mbstring.http_output
```

y basta con poner `default_charset = "utf-8"`

Si usas **mysql toda la collation de Base de datos y tablas debe ser utf8 - utf8_spanish_ci** y en la conexión:

```
$Conex=new mysqli(.....);
$Conex->set_charset("utf8");
```

Por ultimo **tus html debe tambien configurar el utf8** con la siguiente linea:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Si usas bibliotecas o APIs externas también deben configurar UTF-8 porque que ***con algo que falte provocara que tengas problemas de caracteres***.

Se me olvidaba, también configura tu IDE o editor de texto a UTF-8.

Comment: Muchas gracias (Y)

Answer (score 1):

puedes establecer el juego de caracteres cuando estas haciendo el query, estableciendo el juego de caracteres en UTF8 es decir; así lo podrias hacer;

`$con->set_charset("utf8"); //Estableciendo utf8
$sql1= "SELECT * FROM registros";
 $query = $con->query($sql1);`

Comment: Muchas Gracias (Y)