# Porqué me falla esta consulta PHP sólo en dos variables?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código php para el acceso a una base de datos:

```
    $us_usuario = $_POST['us_usuario'];
    $us_clave = $_POST['us_clave'];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT U.us_usuario, U.us_clave, A.hora_inicio, A.hora_fin, A.fecha, A.nombre, A.apellidos, A.prestacion FROM td_agenda_envision A, td_usuario U WHERE U.us_clave = ? AND U.us_usuario = ? AND U.us_ag_alias !='' ");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ss', $us_usuario, $us_clave);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $us_usuario, $us_clave, $hora_inicio, $hora_fin, $fecha, $nombre, $apellidos, $prestacion);

        $arrRespuesta = array();
        $response['success'] = false;

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['success'] = true);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_usuario'] = $us_usuario);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['us_clave'] = $us_clave);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_inicio'] = $hora_inicio);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['hora_fin'] = $hora_fin);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['fecha'] = $fecha);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['nombre'] = $nombre);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['apellidos'] = $apellidos);
            array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['prestacion'] = $prestacion);
        }
echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);
```

?>
Al probarlo tal y como está ahí, no me devuelve nada, ni siquiera error. Sin embargo, si comento las líneas:

array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['nombre'] = $nombre);

array_push($arrRespuesta, $arrRespuesta['apellidos'] = $apellidos);

Sale lo esperado:
[image: Valores mostrados para us_usuario="ALICIA" y us_clave="ALICIA"]
Valores mostrados para us_usuario="ALICIA" y us_clave="ALICIA"

¿Alguna idea de porqué puede ser? tanto nombre como apellidos son del mismo tipo de datos que fecha, sin embargo la fecha no da problema ninguno.
[image: Aquí el resultado de la consulta directamente sobre la base de datos]
Aquí el resultado de la consulta directamente sobre la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, tienes caracteres especiales en los campos "nombre" y "apellidos". Seguramente te esté fallando la codificación de dichos caracteres.

**Apache/PHP**

Mirate [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13557/agregar-caracteres-especiales-utf-8-en-como-%C3%B1-y-acentos-en-mysqli).

**PHP/MySQL**

Mirate [esta respuesta](http://xaviesteve.com/354/acentos-y-enes-aparecen-mal-a%C2%B1-en-php-con-mysql-utf-8-iso-8859-1/). Sobre todo la parte del SET NAMES.

**json_encode**

Puedes echar un vistazo a las distintas opciones que se le pueden pasar a `json_encode` en [este enlace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Prueba con:

```
echo json_encode($arrRespuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

También puedes codificar explicitamente los datos:

```
$arrRespuesta = array_map('utf8_encode', $arrRespuesta);
echo json_encode($arrRespuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: No funcionan esas soluciones, siguen sin salirme nada si dejo el nombre y los apellidos sin comentar.

Comment: Has mirado que error te dá en concreto en el log del servidor?

Comment: End of input at caracter 0 of.

No me dice nada más.

Comment: Ese error suele darse cuando la respuesta que quieres convertir a json es null... Prueba a hacer un `var_dump($arrRespuesta)` antes del json_encode para ver el contenido.

Comment: De todas formas estoy bastante seguro de que es cosa de los caracteres especiales de esos campos. Prueba a borrar los registros que tengan caracteres especiales en dichos campos y prueba.

Comment: Cuando uso ese comando en el json me sale: expected 'a'. Ni idea de que significa eso

Comment: De todas formas, aunque sea por los caracteres especiales (que seguramente sea por eso) ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo? Porque cuando añada nuevos registros es muy probable que tengan esos mismos caracteres.

Comment: Te edito la respuesta y te pongo lo que yo intentaría hacer...

Comment: Vale, he cambiado la codificación en la base de datos y ahora me funciona, muchas gracias.