# Mostrar/cargar Texto enriquecido desde mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, tinymce

Tengo actualmente tinymice con php y mysql. Hasta aqui todo bien, guarda los datos correctamente en la bd con su formato descrito en el editor de texto.
El tema es cuando quiero mostrar esta informacion en un pre, input o parrafo, simplemente me los muestra con los caracteres especiales.
Actualmente hago lo siguiente:

```
echo htmlentities($desc_us);
```

Probe tambien con:

```
echo nl2br($desc_us);
```

pero obtengo datos similares, como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: $desc_us es la variable que trae la descripcion de cada cliente.

Lo que necesito obviamente es que se muestre el texto sin los caracteres especiales, para ser mostrados en el perfil del cliente.
Alguna ayuda u orientacion? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ya intentaste usar `utf8_encode($desc_us);` ?

Comment: @VickMuñoz hola. gracias por responder. Efectivmente, utf8_encode fue una de las primaras opciones que probe, pero me sigue mostrando los caracteres de texto enriquecido.

Comment: Tal vez esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13557/agregar-caracteres-especiales-utf-8-en-como-%C3%B1-y-acentos-en-mysqli) te pueda ayudar, a la hora de insertar utilizas el `utf8_decode($desc_us);`?

Comment: ¿Qué mostraría `$desc_us` sin aplicarle ninguna función? Si necesitas decodificar algo, no te recomiendo usar `utf8_decode`, sino que configures bien el entorno de forma global: conexión a la base de datos, encabezados del HTML, codificación del servidor, información en la base de datos. Cuando todo está bien configurado, no tienes que andar pasando los datos por funciones de codificación cada vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por responder. Muestra lo siguiente: <p>Laboratorio Mario S.A., es una empresa familiar.</p>
<p>Cuenta con los siguientes servicios:</p>
<ul>
<li>Servicio 1.</li>
<li>Servicio 2.</li>
<li>Servicio 3.</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Nos encontramos en, Mi direccion 123.</p>.
el ingreso a la base de datos lo hago a traves del plugin de tinymice.

Comment: @VickMuñoz cuando inserto lo hago a traves del editor de texto tinymice. no paso por ninguna codificacion, mas que la que ya tiene la base de datos. Corrigeme si estoy equivocado en cuanto a si sera a lo que te referias.

Comment: Y, ¿por qué no lo muestras tal cual? ¿Acaso no estás en un HTML?

Comment: @A.Cedano porque ese es mi problema. Lo que escribi en el comentario anterior, es lo que se muestra en el HTML (tal cual esta en el comentario), con las etiquetas y todo. Necesito que mantenga el formato pero no muestre las etiquetas.

Comment: Es muy extraño eso, ¿no será que tienes alguna plantilla o algo instalado que impide que el HTML se renderice? O no es para nada un HTML... de serlo se mostraría correctamente.